# "Multiple bindings" error when calling ninject2.Get<ConcreteClass>()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'd like to do something like this:

```
ConcreteClass foo = ninject2.Get<ConcreteClass>(
    new ConstructorArgument("bar", "qux"));

ninject2.Bind<ConcreteClass>().ToConstant(foo);

...

ConcreteClass foo = ninject2.Get<ConcreteClass>(); // fail!
```

When I try, I get the error `Error activating ConcreteClass. More than one matching bindings are available.`

What is happening here?

Comment: I really dont see why this merited a -1 from someone. Even if I didnt think it was worth a +1 (I do, I'd have neutralsied the downvote as it didnt give a reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOTB, Ninject (esp. v2 - in v1, it was an optional setting that defaulted to on) internally generates implicit bindings for concrete classes to themselves, with the default scoping (Transient in v2). These registrations get added into the Bindings list as if you'd added them yourself via.

```
Bind<ConcreteClass>().ToSelf(); // .InTransientScope(); -- But that would be implicit
```

If you need anything different in your binding, you register a `Bind`ing before it gets auto-bound, with **Your customisation bit** a la:

```
Bind<ConcreteClass>().ToSelf().<<Your Customisation Bit>>;
```

In this case, your remedy is to use something like:

```
Bind<ConcreteClass>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument( "foo", "bar");
```

Where `InSingletonScope()` would match your current code in that it looks like you only ever want to instantiate one. In general, as covered in other answers, one shouldnt necessarily grab for `InSingletonScope` as a tool of first resort.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a vague notion of what was going on, but your answer made it clear - and now my code is working as intended. I love Ninject, but I wish it was better documented.

Comment: @Metaphile: I see an edit on http://github.com/ninject/ninject/wikis/why-use-ninject in the last few days - so subscribe to the feed and keep the faith! (Seriously though, the source and the tests are so straightforward, the USL option is the way to go)